# How prove this limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}g(x)f'(nx)dx=0$

Tags: analysis

> let $f'(x)$ be  continuation on $R$, and $f(x)=f(x+2\pi),\forall x\in R$, and such
>   $|f'(x)|\le 1$,Now define $g(x)$,such for any $x_{1},x_{2}\in [0,1]$, we have
>   $$|g(x_{1})-g(x_{2})|\le \sqrt{|x_{1}-x_{2}|}$$
>
> show that
>   $$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}g(x)f'(nx)dx=0$$

This problem is form analysis problem book excise (MIn hui Xie)

Maybe we can use [Dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem),but I can't use this condition

$$|g(x_{1})-g(x_{2})|\le \sqrt{|x_{1}-x_{2}|}\Longrightarrow \left|\dfrac{g(x_{1})-g(x_{2})}{x_{1}-x_{2}}\right|\le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|x_{1}-x_{2}|}}$$
because $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|x_{1}-x_{2}|}}\in (0,+\infty),\forall x_{1},x_{2}\in [0,1]$,so $g$ is not [Lipschitz continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity),Then I can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[a] = \{ x : |x| \le |a| \}$ for any $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

$f'$ is continuous and periodic and $\int_{[t,t+2\pi]} f' = 0$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, from the condition given.

$g$ is continuous, from the condition given.

[With $[0,1]$ being compact, the above conditions are all we actually need.]

Let $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f' \in [p]$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and $g \in [q]$ on $[0,1]$

Also $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

For any $ε > 0$:

Let $a > 0$ such that $g(x+[a]) \subseteq g(x) + [ε]$ for any $x \in [0,1]$, by uniform continuity.

For any $n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n \ge \max(\frac{2\pi}{a},\frac{2\pi}{ε})$:

Let $c = \lfloor \frac{n}{2\pi} \rfloor$

$\int_{[0,1]} g(x) f'(nx)\ dx$

$ = \sum_{k=1}^c \int_{\frac{2\pi}{n}[k-1,k]} g(x) f'(nx)\ dx + \int_{[\frac{2\pi}{n}c,1]} g(x) f'(nx)\ dx$

$ \in \sum_{k=1}^c \int_{\frac{2\pi}{n}[k-1,k]} \left( g(\frac{2\pi}{n}k) + [ε] \right) f'(nx)\ dx + (1-\frac{2\pi}{n}c) [pq]$ [because $\frac{2\pi}{n} < a$]

$ = \sum_{k=1}^c \int_{\frac{2\pi}{n}[k-1,k]} [ε] f'(nx)\ dx + (1-\frac{2\pi}{n}c) [pq]$ [because $\int_{\frac{2\pi}{n}[k-1,k]} f'(nx)\ dx = 0$]

$ \subseteq \sum_{k=1}^c \frac{2\pi}{n} [ε] [p] + \frac{2\pi}{n} [pq]$

$ \subseteq [εp] + [εpq] = ([p]+[pq])ε$

Therefore $\int_{[0,1]} g(x) f'(nx)\ dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: It's Nice! ..  +1

Comment: @chinamath: I think this result that I've proven is used on the function $f' = x \mapsto e^{inx}$ to show something about Fourier transforms but I can't remember.